# Generating random key

Tags: python

I have an assignment to generate random key in order to implement one-time-pad algorithm.

```
alphabet_in_26_mod = {
    'A':0,'B':1,'C':2,
    'D':3,'E':4,'F':5,
    'J':6,'H':7,'I':8,
    'G':9,'K':10,'L':11,
    'M':12,'N':13,'O':14,
    'P':15,'Q':16,'R':17,
    'S':18,'T':19,'U':20,
    'V':21,'W':22,'X':23,
    'Y':24,'Z':25
}

text ="hello world"


def find_letter(mod26):
    letter = ''
    for k,v in alphabet_in_26_mod.items():

        if mod26 == v:
            letter = k
            break

    return letter



def generate_random_key():
    length = len(text)-1
    key=""
    while length >= 0:
        c = dt.now().microsecond
        random  = c%26
        key = key + find_letter(random)
        length -=1
    return key



key =generate_random_key()
print(key)
```

the problem is that the function generate_random_key() returns nothing but repeated letter. i debugged the code and i found that the function do what it supposed to do.

the output
FFFFFFFFFFF

when i debuged the code, the output was
'YRVKRUOHYNH'

Comment: When I run your code I get seemingly random letters all the time, so can you elaborate on what your problem/question is exactly? To me the code you posted seems to work.

Comment: did you try `random` library and `string` library instead?

Comment: What is `dt.now()`? Did you `from datetime import datetime as dt`? Add the imports to make this a running script. Which operating system? I think the resolution is 12 microseconds on Windows, Since each loop is about the same execution time, you'll get non-randomizing symetries in the output.

Comment: Why define a dictionary that does `letter -> number`? Just use `string.ascii_uppercase` take one character from it by index, which will be from 0-25

Comment: You could use the timeit module. `int(timeit.default_timer() *1_000_000)` will give you better resolution.

Comment: @tdelaney 12 microseconds would be great! Compared to the several **milli**seconds I'm actually getting with that.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode - Looks like I got my micros and millis mixed up! And now that I think about it, its 15 and change _milliseconds_.

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, I would've guessed 16 ms based on previous experiences with `time.time()`. Added my experiment as answer now.

Comment: @tdelaney  int(timeit.default_timer() *1_000_000) solved the issue. thanks

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode - Its based on how often microsoft foreces thread swaps and can range from 64 to 100 times a second, based on platform. So, 15.625 mS to 10 mS, depending. There may be MS versions that do it differently and it can be changed from the default. So, its all a guess.

Comment: @tdelaney Actually, after plugging my laptop in (and improving the code), I'm getting jumps always very close to 1 millisecond (see much updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

at the first you could use a string instead of dictionary.

For example:

```
Alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

print(Alphabet[2]) # Return : c
print(Alphabet[10]) # Return : k
```

And there is no need for `find_letter` function because you can get the letter directly from `Alphabet` variable.

Also you could use `random` library instead of using microsecond to get a random number:

```
def generate_random_key(length):
    import random
    result = ''
    for i in range(length):
        result += random.choices(Alphabet)[0]
    return result

print(generate_random_key(5))
```

Comment: in the assignment i must avoid using any library to get a random event. thanks

Comment: but i get the solution by using  int(timeit.default_timer() *1_000_000)

Comment: there is no info about the assignment but `random` library is built-in python same as `time` library witch you're using it

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting repeated characters because the code runs too fast for `dt.now().microsecond` to give you different results. Especially if you're on Windows. Let's do a test, fetching more and more times until we have ten different ones.

Typical results for me on Windows, shows that I can get the same time (and thus same microsecond) *hundreds* of times in a row (and when they do increase, then usually by about 1000 microseconds):

```
time                        occurrences  ms-delta
-------------------------------------------------
2021-10-07 22:09:14.116604       90        None
2021-10-07 22:09:14.117607      598        1003
2021-10-07 22:09:14.118601      641         994
2021-10-07 22:09:14.119603      647        1002
2021-10-07 22:09:14.120598      653         995
2021-10-07 22:09:14.121597      651         999
2021-10-07 22:09:14.122593      653         996
2021-10-07 22:09:14.123593      654        1000
2021-10-07 22:09:14.124592      653         999
2021-10-07 22:09:14.125590      653         998
```

When you're *debugging*, you're not fetching the times so quickly in a row, so there's plenty of time between the calls for the microsecond to change.

Typical results on Linux:

```
time                        occurrences  ms-delta
-------------------------------------------------
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256903        1        None
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256914        1          11
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256916        1           2
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256917        1           1
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256918        1           1
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256919        1           1
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256920        1           1
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256921        1           1
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256923        1           2
2021-10-07 20:10:23.256924        1           1
```

The experiment's code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVG9TsQwDN7zFJbQqanUnqhYTkg3sTPwBiXxQaQ0rhL3Tvf0pXEJLQMDnhJ//n6cjHf@pPB0GuM8XyINYHtGdgOCG0aKvN37BJaVzDjGyEQ@laGPSNP4fm/AJe8MKvUAL@Q9GlaZm@AMWudTAx6D9i6xFk5d1wpKXSjCOiQYuFCEdXbUlo@Bbg28UsBMLNIitzqLSWqge1zwJcUb5nxqjC6wrmSPP4qMmWLEYBZJGFJr0XNf1YXa/reEildHU46YI6ttv73ZsqWEfpaHWO1kansYqA4nW8Fhz/sNd13KuP6x7IMV2ePgTKSEhpZGCwXft7@/YJc2E@f5Cw)):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from itertools import groupby, islice

# Collect
times = ((time, len(list(group)))
         for time, group in groupby(iter(dt.now, None)))
times = list(islice(times, 10))

# Report
print('time                        occurrences  ms-delta')
print('-------------------------------------------------')
previous = None
for time, occurrences in times:
    print(time,
          '%8d' % occurrences,
          '%11s' % (previous and time.microsecond - previous.microsecond))
    previous = time
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely calculate the entire key within one tick of the system clock, choosing the same letter on each loop. `datetime.dateime.now()` is based on the system timer, whose resolution varies widely with operating system. On a Windows client, its typically based on a 64 beats per second granularity, or 15.625 milliseonds.

Over time, python has implemented several higher resolution timers that are more consistent across operating system. Another option is

```
int(timeit.default_timer() *1_000_000)
```

You could also use

```
time.time_ns()/100
```

Your system likely doens't have nanosecond resolution and the division is there to get you back to 100 nanosecond numbers that your system may be capable of.

Comment: `time_ns()` doesn't seem to be any better, increases by about 1,000,000 for me (i.e., 1 millisecond). I think it's the same as `time()`, just in the format of nanoseconds as ints.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode - good to know.I'm using a list comprension `t = [time_ns() for _ in range(100)]` and on my slow laptop, the best resolution I get is .5 uS. but I'm on linux, so not exactly apples to apples.

Answer (score -1):

For generating cryptographically secure secrets, there is a built-in module for that (even `random` should not be used for cryptography, much less timestamp-based direct generation): https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Also, no need to map out the entire alphabet-number, you can convert on the fly with something like:

```
def char_to_mod26(ch):
    ch = ch.upper()  # support upper+lowercase
    return ord(ch) - ord('A')  # ASCII 'A' is code 65 


def mod36_to_char(mod36):
    return chr(mod36 + ord('A'))  # always returns uppercase
```

Comment: This is not really helpful if OP's assignment is to generate random keys manually.

Comment: pardon my pedantism, but at the time of writing, `manually` is not actually part of the description.

Comment: That is true! I jumped to my conclusion due to the code that is posted in the question. If you are right OP will probably be more than happy to discover the `random`-module. I guess we'll have to wait and see :-)